# How to trigger Ctrl+z,Ctrl+y on button click. I am using Angular for this

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a created a Component in Angular. In that component a textarea is there where user can write. I want a functionality that, on a button click user will undo or redo there change. I tried using `document.execCommand('undo', false, null);` and `document.execCommand('redo', false, null);`. Both of this didn't work. I am using Angular 6. For creating Text-area and buttons I am using Angular Material

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1u3k77

- Inject Document `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document`
- use `execCommand()` to trigger any desired command